# When I get a page via cURL, it is returned badly encoded

Tags: php, curl

I've been trying to grab one page via Curl but fail to do it properly as the page returns badly encoded. Here's the page: http://www.movinsane.com/play13.php?vid=107628
Would you please tell me what how to do it with the help of PHP's Curl so that I can view it properly. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe the webpage is sent gzipped?

Comment: can you post the output?

Comment: Duplicate: Same name different account - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490679/curl-cant-get-a-webpage-properly

Answer (score 0):

If Scott M. is right, you just need to set the encoding to understand gzip:

```
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
```

Comment: According to firebug, it indeed it is gzipped