# Curl can't get a webpage properly

Tags: php, curl

I've been trying to grab one page via Curl but fail to do it properly as the page is returned badly encoded. Here's the page: http://www.movinsane.com/play13.php?vid=107628 Would you please tell me what how to do it with the help of PHP's Curl so that I can view it properly. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
$c = curl_init('http://www.movinsane.com/play13.php?vid=108561');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
$sourse = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);

echo $sourse;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a curl related problem. It downloads the content properly. You have to include a `<base href="http://www.movinsane.com/"/>` before writing out the `$sourse`.

My opinion is that these type of actions are phishings.